# How to apply add_event_listener() on newly created element?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, appendchild

I am using this script to apply add_event_listener() when the DOM is already loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",regFunct,false);
```

then I list all the function inside `regFunct` function.
all the function inside the `regFunct` which is loaded from the server are working except the newly created element using `appendChild()`.

```
function regFunct(){
    //doSomething1
    //doSomething2 (create new HTML element)

    //doSomething3 (apply add_event_listener() after
    //              the new element created by doSomething2)
}
```

doSomething3 is not working.

Comment: look on live() in jquery http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: And what about using document.addEventListener("load",regFunct,false);
 instead? does it make any difference?

Comment: @Haim: im not using jQuery for now...

Comment: What does `doSomething1`, `doSomething2` and `doSomething3` look like?

Comment: @CronosS: load nedd more time... it needs all the img element to be loaded...

Answer (score 0):

For elements that are created only *after* the `DOMContentLoaded` event already fired, you can create a *delegate listener*.

Here's one possible approach. Let's assume you want to listen to the  `click` event on a dynamically added `button` that has the `id` `myNewButton`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  // lets create and add the button only when DOMContentLoaded has already fired
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.id = "myNewButton";
  btn.type = "button";
  btn.textContent = "My shiny new button";
  document.getElementById('app').appendChild(btn);
})

// before the above is executed, let's add a delegate click listener
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'myNewButton') {
    event.target.textContent += " was clicked!";
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Please note that this only works for events that *bubble*. Examples of events that don't bubble by default: `scroll`, `blur`, `focus`.